# Sending multipart text and html email in Fat Free Framework

Tags: multipart, fat-free-framework

Currently I'm using the following code to send my e-mails in Fat Free Framework:

```
$smtp = new SMTP ( $f3->get('MAILHOST'), $f3->get('MAILPORT'), $f3->get('MAILPROTOCOL'), $f3->get('MAILUSER'), $f3->get('MAILPW') );
        $smtp->set('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'); 
        $smtp->set('Errors-to', '<$my_mail_address>');
        $smtp->set('To', "<$my_mail_address>");
        $smtp->set('From', '"$my_mailer_name" <$my_mail_address>');
        $smtp->set('Subject', "$subject");
        $smtp->set('Date', date("r"));
        $smtp->set('Message-Id',generateMessageID());
$smtp->send(Template::instance()->render('emails/'.$mailTemplate.'.html'));
```

And it works like a charm. But I would like to add a text version to this e-mail.

Is there a way to do this within the Fat Free Framework smtp plugin?
If so, how should I do this?
And if not, how else should I do this in F3?

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/blob/master/smtp.php), it seems that it's not possible to send two versions (HTML+text) of the same message in one email. You can attach the text version as a separate file though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it can send a multiplart text + html mail. The SMTP class is just a protocol implementation, so it might feel a little bit bare-bone at this point. You basically need to prepare your mail body with the multipart like this:

```
$text = 'Hello world.';
$html = 'Hello <b>world</b>';

$smtp = new \SMTP();
$hash=uniqid(NULL,TRUE);
$smtp->set('From', 'info@domain.com');
$smtp->set('To', 'info@domain.com');
$smtp->set('Content-Type', 'multipart/alternative; boundary="'.$hash.'"');
$smtp->set('Subject', 'Multipart test');

$eol="\r\n";
$body  = '--'.$hash.$eol;
$body .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8'.$eol;
$body .= $text.$eol.$eol;
$body .= '--'.$hash.$eol;
$body .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'.$eol.$eol;
$body .= $html.$eol;

$smtp->send($body,true);
```

Comment: This will not work if there is an attachment attached to the mail. Can you elaborate how to do this?

Comment: Actually just add `$->smtp->attach($path);` before you send the message

Comment: This is what I've meant: When you add an attachment (using ->smtp->attach($path) and use the method described above for adding a text version to the mail, the attachment is broken and will display like a huge chunk of text.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, but my mailer plugin does it like that and i have no problems sending multipart mails with text/html and attachments.

Comment: What do you mean by "my mailer plugin". You don't use the mail class of f3 then?